# Roblox money distribution system not working

Tags: lua, roblox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm997.jpg)I was trying to make a money collection system for the person on the stone grey team, but it won't work. What it should do is take the wealth value from the province, multiply by 0.02 and add that onto the total amount of money for the person. The leaderboard has the 'Finances' on there, but the value stays at 0 no matter what. The output bar is also blank.

```
local map = game.Workspace.map
local rp = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

local provinces = {
    map.province1,
    map.province2,
    map.province3,
    map.province4,
    map.province5,
    map.province6,
    map.province7,
    map.province8,
    map.province9
}

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    local stats = Instance.new("BoolValue")
    stats.Name = "leaderstats"
    stats.Parent = plr
    local finances = Instance.new("NumberValue")
    finances.Name = "Finances"
    finances.Parent = plr.leaderstats
end)

-- below here i have problems, above this seems to work normally

rp.TaxPaymentsCheque.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr)
    for start = 1, #provinces  do
        local provincegrowing = provinces[start]
        if provincegrowing.BrickColor == BrickColor.new("Dark stone grey") then
            local finances = plr.leaderstats.Finances.Value
            local wealth = provincegrowing.ProvinceWealth.Value
            local taxmodifier = 0.02
            local revenue = wealth * taxmodifier
            local oldfinanceamount = finances
            finances = oldfinanceamount + revenue
        end
    end
end)
```

There is also a picture if it can be of any use.

Comment: You need to set the value directly instead of updating a copy (i.e. the variable) - `plr.leaderstats.Finances.Value = oldfinanceamount + revenue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the reason why you don't see any change is because you're not actually changing the `Finances` Value

Instead what you are doing is saving Finances' Value to a variable and changing the variable

```lua
local number = SomeIntValue.Value
number = number * 5
-- is practically the same as saying
local number = 1
number = number * 5
```

It doesn't actually set the IntValue's value
To do that, do something like this

```lua
local number = SomeIntValue.Value
number = number * 5
SomeIntValue.Value = number
-- or
SomeIntValue.Value = SomeIntValue.Value * 5
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for some reason, I tried both your and Rylee's solutions for this.

Comment: But it's definitely the answer. Make sure the rest of the code also works, especially the BrickColor comparison might be invalid. Make sure the the finance part is called.

Comment: So I've changed the code a bit and the event seems to be firing, but the value continues to remain 0.